# How to send mail with curl utf-8 conform

Tags: curl, utf-8

I got a problem with utf-8 encoding in my program. I call curl with:

```
curl --url "smtps://smtp.myprov.com:465" --ssl-reqd --mail-from "tell@mywebsite.de" --mail-rcpt "mstest@googlemail.com" --upload-file mail.txt --user "lalaland:secret" --insecure
```

the mail.txt is utf-8 encoded without BOM.

It content is:

```
From: ##FROM##
To: ##TO##
Subject: Du bekommst Information

Hallo ##NAME##,

Du hast gerade eine Information abgefragt. Sie wird dir umgehend erteilt.
Die dazugehörende Transaktion ist ##ID##

Beste Grüße 

Dein Team
```

The ##TAG## are replaced by the proper information.

The send is successful and I receive the mail on my account.
Everything is shiny in OSX mail and gmail over chrome. But not with Windows live mail. The german "umlaute" are not shown correctly. It looks like a typical misinterpretation of utf-8 as ASCII. What am I missing?

Comment: _“What am I missing?”_ – that you should tell the receiving client about the encoding of your mail contents …? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied the mail text from a sample. I didn't know anything about encoding, my fault. This is how the header should look:

```
From: ##FROM##
To: ##TO##
Subject: Du bekommst Information
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
```